# Add printer using web browser

Tags: printing, hta

I'm looking for a solution to add a printer (Windows) from a web browser. I found some HTA file solution, however HTA files run outdated version of IE which is, in my situation, unusable.

Have anybody been through this?

Thank you for any solution,
Best regards,
Michal Puchmertl

Comment: Adding a printer is an OS task, use OS instead of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to install is a network printer, you can use the following code provided that the user knows the name of the printer and the host name or IP address of the server.

Save the following code as an HTA file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Printer Install</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME = "Printer Install"
     SCROLL = "Yes"
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
     INNERBORDER = "yes"
     BORDER = "dialog"
     NAVIGABLE = "no"
     CONTEXTMENU = "no"
     ICON = ""

</head>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

Sub Window_Onload

     Self.ResizeTo 450, 400
     Self.MoveTo 420, 190

End Sub

Set Objnetwork = CreateObject("wscript.network")

Sub Install
     printserver = document.getElementById("server").value
     strPrinterName = document.getElementById("name").value
     strprinterpath = "\\" & printserver & "\" & strPrinterName
     objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection strprinterpath
     MsgBox "Successfully mapped" & "\\" & printserver & "\" & strPrinterName

End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body>

Printer Server: <input type="text" id="server"></input><p>
Printer Name: <input type="text" id="name"></input><p>
<input type="button" onclick="Install" value="Install"></input><p>

</body>
</html>
```